# Когда применять unset в php7

Tags: php, оптимизация, память, php7

Здравствуйте, [посмотрел выступления зендовца](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yYBr09BbqI), [почитал статьи на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/257999/). Поле чего возник логичный, но философский вопрос про оптимизацию кода.

Теперь

```
echo 'Hello', $username, '!';
```

медленнее, чем

```
echo 'Hello, {$username}!'; // вероятно, фигурные — лишние
```

Теперь что-то вроде

```
for ($i = 0, $l = count($arr); $i < $l; $i++) {
    $str = 'Hello, World';
}
```

Равноценно:

```
$str = 'Hello, World';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {}
```

Потому что строка неизменяемая и интерпретатор об этом знает. То есть напишешь `unset($str)` в конце этого блока, как будет медленней работать… Мне это странно. Объясните, пожалуйста, подкрепляя источниками как теперь оптимальней писать код? Где писать unset-ы.

Comment: это называется premature optimization. подробнее можно почитать тут http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Не заметил ни какой разницы с `echo`. То больше, то меньше, раз на раз не приходится. Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d87609e183ce413835e8af8f208b9074320dbc3a

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы имели ввиду
    echo "Hello, {$username}!"
а не 
    echo 'Hello, {$username}!

Что касается unset() - эта конструкция очищает память выделенную под хранение данных переменной, а так же память выделенную под имя переменной. Если планируется несколько присвоений к одной и той же переменной, естественно unset между этими присвоениями будет выполнять лишнюю операцию. https://habrahabr.ru/post/134784/

Что касается новой оптимизации, вроде "Неизменяемых массивов": в частном случае - если переменная неизменна или интерпретатор может определить, что изменений нет, он сможет использовать значение этой переменной в разных участках кода с наименьшими затратами по памяти. unset() переменной может быть расценено интерпретатором как изменение такой переменной и использование ее значения в разных фрагментах исполняемого кода будет невозможным. https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/318008/